# My Website Crashes In IE9

Tags: javascript, crash, internet-explorer-9

My website is crashing sporadically in IE9 on a certain page.  The page has a lot of Javascript, including Twitter Bootstrap, JQuery, Google Analytics, Olark, Facebook, ZeroClipboard, and a lot of custom script, which is mostly compiled from CoffeeScript. I also use a good bit of CSS3, even some animation stuff, but I have removed all of that from this page (I think).

This is a hard crash of the IE executable.  F12 script debugger does not catch this or give any hint what it might be.  Windows event viewer logs the crash, but there is no useful detail.

The page is fine on all other major browsers on Windows, Mac and iOS.  I'm at a loss of even how to troubleshoot this.  I've just been hacking at various stuff.

The crash is somewhat at random. However, you should be able to reproduce like this:

1. Go here: http://slotted.co/sheets/edit/94cvk6as
2. Click "Delete This Sheet" then "Cancel" repeatedly

After a few times, it should crash.

NOTE: If the above link is broken, go the home page and create a new sheet.

Any ideas of how to approach this are much appreciated.

UPDATE: If you cannot reproduce with the steps above, F5 a couple of times in between clicks of the link.

Comment: No problems here either. Did a bit of profiling and found that over 10,000 regular expression executions have taken place. Perhaps it's a memory issue with your machine?

Comment: I have more that 1Gb free RAM when it crashes

Answer (score 1):

1. Get into a position where you can preciptiate the crash reliably by automating the button clicks using Selinium, or something similar.
2. Binary chop the non essential js, retying the tests (A B then back to A) to confirm you've found it.

Comment: I'm trying this method. I've been at it for 5 hours, and I got down to the bare bones (jquery, bootstrap, mustache, custom), and it still crashes. It will be much harder to start dismantling my custom JS.  One interesting thing is that it seems to crash much less frequently with ZeroClipboard removed.  ZeroClipboard uses Flash.  Still crashes randomly though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the problem was ZeroClipboard. Let me elaborate. Zero Clipboard comes with two flash files `ZeroClipboard.swf` and `ZeroClipboard10.swf`.  I had been using the former.

I switched to `ZeroClipboard10.swf`, and the problem goes away.

It did not *seem* to go away at first.  Event after completely removing ZeroClipboard, I was still able to reproduce a crash.  My theory is that IE was retaining some harmful state in cache.

I can't say for sure.  What I can say is that I can no longer reproduce the crash after switching to `ZeroClipboard10.swf`  I believe that change was the thing that made the difference.